# Using map functionality in shell script

Tags: java, bash, shell

I have below shellscript

```
MYMAP12=$(java -jar hello-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar)
echo  "==="
echo ${MYMAP12}
```

The output of java -jar hello-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar will be map `{one=one, two=two, three=three}`
how to get each element from the key in shell script

I tried  `echo ${MYMAP12{one}}` but it gave me an error

Comment: At best, the Java program is outputting something intended for a different consumer. At worst, it's just outputting nonsensical pseudocode. Either change `hello-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` to output something that `bash` *can* use, or use the Java program from an environment that *can* parse the output.

Answer (score 2):

As @chepner implied, the Java code is just outputting a text string which has to be parsed and manipulated in bash to make it useful.  There are no doubt several ways to do this, here is one which uses pure bash (i.e. no external programs):

```
# This is the text string supplied by Java
MYMAP12='{one=one, two=two, three=three}'

# Create an associative array called 'map'
declare -A map

# Remove first and last characters ( { and } )
MYMAP12=${MYMAP12#?}
MYMAP12=${MYMAP12%?}
# Remove ,
MYMAP12=${MYMAP12//,/}

# The list is now delimited by spaces, the default in a shell
for item in $MYMAP12
do
    # This splits around '='
    IFS='=' read key val <<< $item
    map[$key]=$val
done

echo "keys: ${!map[@]}"
echo "values: ${map[@]}"
```

Gives:

```
keys: two three one
values: two three one
```

EDIT:

You should to use the correct tool for the job, if you need an associative array (map, hash table, dictionary) then you need a language with that feature.  These include `bash`, `ksh`, `awk`, `perl`, `ruby`, `python` and `C++`.

You can extract the keys and values using a POSIX shell (`sh`) but you cannot store them in an associative array since `sh` does not have that feature.  The best you can do is a generic *list*, which is just a text string of whitespace separated values.  What you can do is to write a lookup function which emulates it:

```
get_value() {
    map="$1"
    key="$2"

    for pair in $MYMAP12
    do  
        if [ "$key" = "${pair%=*}" ]
        then
            value="${pair#*=}"
            # Remove last character ( , or } )
            value=${value%?}
            echo "$value"
            return 0
        fi
    done

    return 1
}

MYMAP12='{kone=one, ktwo=two, kthree=three}'

# Remove first character ( { )
MYMAP12=${MYMAP12#?}

val=$(get_value "$MYMAP12" "ktwo")
echo "value for 'ktwo' is $val"
```

Gives:

```
value for 'ktwo' is two
```

Using this function you can also test for the presence of a key, for example:

```
if get_value "$MYMAP12" "kfour"
then
    echo "key kfour exists"
else
    echo "key kfour does not exist"
fi
```

Gives:

```
key kfour does not exist
```

Note that this is inefficient compared to an associative array since we are sequentially searching a list, although with a short list of only three keys you won't see any difference.

Comment: I wanted to do this in Shell, I am getting an error at declare -A map on using this in shell script. Probably the code above is in bash.

Comment: Please give the error message. I used bash because you have the bash tag on your question. Note that my answer states "pure bash". Please define what you mean by "Shell", which a generic term. If you mean you want to use `sh` (POSIX shell) then you are out of luck since `sh` does not support associative arrays.

Answer (score 1):

if you change your output format to the right hand side

```
$ x="( [one]=foo [two]=bar [three]=baz )"
```

then, you can use `bash` associative arrays

```
$ declare -A map="$x"
$ echo "${map[one]}"
foo
```